# sparklyR cannot see any hive database

Tags: apache-spark, sparkr, sparklyr

I'm using SparklyR to connect to an external spark cluster in a client. I can successfully connect to the cluster but I cannot see any database in there except the default db (which is empty). I have all hadoop config files (i.e. core-site.xml, yarn-site.xml, hive-site.xml) in my client under `$HADOOP_CONF_DIR` and here is my code

```
library(sparklyr)
library(dplyr)
sc <- spark_connect(master = "yarn-client", app_name="test")
data <- tbl(sc, sql('SELECT * FROM db_name.table_name LIMIT 10'))
```

I also try to list the databases using the following command and it only shows `default`.

```
src_databases(sc)
```

Do I need to have the config files in any other location as well?
What's missing?

Comment: What distribution are you using and what version of spark ? If you are on HDP3.x, you have Spark2.3 and Hive3 which Spark is not able to communicate with, you need to import Hive Warehouse Connector https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDP3/HDP-3.1.4/developing-spark-applications/content/using_spark_hive_warehouse_connector.html

Comment: I'm using CDH, spark v. 2.20

Comment: my client has spark 2.4.3 though, is this the problem?

Comment: Possibly, there are a lot of changes between 2.2 and 2.4, but I would have a look at the Hive version used, if it's 3.x you'll need the library

Comment: See https://github.com/sparklyr/sparklyr/issues/2202, please also comment on the issue.